# target input by type and name (selector)

Tags: jquery

I need to change some checkbox inputs to hidden inputs for some but not all inputs on a page.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductCode"value="396P4"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductCode"value="401P4"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="ProductCode"value="F460129">
```

The jquery code below only selects the input by type which causes all check boxes to changed to hidden inputs Is there a way to check for both type of input="checkbox" and name="ProductCode" as the selector so I can specifically target those that I want to change?

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
var name = $(this).attr('name'); // grab name of original
var value = $(this).attr('value'); // grab value of original
var html = '<input type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="'+value+'" />';
$(this).after(html).remove(); // add new, then remove original input
});
```

Answer (score 318, accepted):

You want a **[multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)**

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='ProductCode']").each(function(){ ...
```

or

```
$("input:checkbox[name='ProductCode']").each(function(){ ...
```

It would be better to use a CSS class to identify those that you want to select however as a lot of the modern browsers implement the `document.getElementsByClassName` method which will be used to select elements and be much faster than selecting by the `name` attribute

Comment: Both worked for me but I used the second method. THX, I have another question but I'll make a new question.

Answer (score 24):

You can combine attribute selectors this way:

```
$("[attr1=val][attr2=val]")...
```

so that an element has to satisfy both conditions. Of course you can use this for more than two. Also, don't do `[type=checkbox]`. jQuery has a selector for that, namely [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) so the end result is:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=ProductCode]")...
```

Attribute selectors are slow however so the recommended approach is to use ID and class selectors where possible. You could change your markup to:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ProductCode" name="ProductCode"value="396P4"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="ProductCode" name="ProductCode"value="401P4"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="ProductCode" name="ProductCode"value="F460129">
```

allowing you to use the *much* faster selector of:

```
$("input.ProductCode")...
```

Comment: Obviously this works as well but I can only give one person credit for the right answer. :) One thing thought is I can't target by class cause I have no access to markup unless I add a class and what point would that make. But Thx!!!

Answer (score 7):

```
input[type='checkbox', name='ProductCode']
```

That's the CSS way and I'm almost sure it will work in jQuery.