# if ..else if condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to hide and show fields using on change function while clicking radio button based on the value in if..else if condition, unfortunately, it not working properly.if this code is correct?? can anyone say me?? thanks in advance...

```
 form do |f|
   f.inputs do
   f.input :name,label:"customer name"
   f.input :service_type, as: :radio, :label => "Payment Type", :collection => [ " Bike ", " Auto " , " Car ", "Bus" ]
end
f.actions
end
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#customer_two_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_three_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_four_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_multiple_wheel_input').hide();

$('#new_customer input[type=radio][name="customer[service_type]"]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "Bike") {
        $('#customer_two_wheel_input').show();
        alert($(this).val())
    }
    else if (this.value == "Auto") {
        $('#customer_three_wheel_input').show();
        alert($(this).val())
    }

    else if (this.value == "Car") {
        $('#customer_four_wheel_input').show();
        alert($(this).val())
    }

    else  {
        $('#customer_multiple_wheel_input').show();
        alert($(this).val())
    }

});
});
```

Comment: The alerts works? have you got any console errors?

Comment: Are they supposed to hide when you click on something?

Comment: What is this `form do |f|
   f.inputs do
   f.input :name,label:"customer name"
   f.input :service_type, as: :radio, :label => "Payment Type", :collection => [ " Bike ", " Auto " , " Car ", "Bus" ]
end
f.actions
end` ?? Where is the `HTML` code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: post a fiddle for better understanding

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/Lyojgqd6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line

```
 $('#new_customer input[type=radio][name="customer[service_type]"]').change(function() {
```

to (I modified jquery selector)

```
 $('#new_customer input[type=radio][name^=customer]').change(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since name is a unique field you can use

```
$('#new_customer input:radio[name="customer[service_type]"]').change(function() {
```

instead of

```
$('#new_customer input[type=radio][name="customer[service_type]"]').change(function() {
```

See [target input by type and name (selector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221094/target-input-by-type-and-name-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly, except that, your previously selected `divs` are not getting hidden when you select a radio button. For this, move your JS code to hide those `divs` inside the `.change()` function, and add CSS to initially hide them.

CSS:

```
#customer_two_wheel_input,
#customer_three_wheel_input,
#customer_four_wheel_input,
#customer_multiple_wheel_input{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#new_customer input[type=radio][name="customer[service_type]"]').change(function() {

        $('#customer_two_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_three_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_four_wheel_input').hide();
        $('#customer_multiple_wheel_input').hide();

        if (this.value == "Bike") {
            ..
        }
        ..
    });
});
```