# How do I make the search box that jquery datatables renders accessible?

Tags: jquery, datatables, accessibility, wai-aria

When using jquery datatables, including a search (filter) box in the dom, I get an accessibility error citing 3.3.2 Input field has no description.

How can I use jquery to add an aria-label to the search box?

This is the code rendered by datatables:

`<label>
<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="data-table" style="z-index: 2147483646; position: relative;">
</label>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute The official documentation states you can use `aria-label="Search"`

Comment: @Michelangelo, the code is rendered dynamically by datatables, so I can't edit it.  I'm looking for a Javascript or jquery solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Saw it later, but you can use the script in the answer. Should work. When do you get the error on runtime or when the user tries to click the search input? Oh, I see you aswered yourself, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***
While my original answer below solved the one accessibility error, it left another related error: Form control label is missing text.

For some reason datatables wraps the search box in an empty label tag.

The following two lines will solve both accessibility errors:

`$('input[type="search"]').unwrap(); //removes the empty parent label tag that surrounds this
$('input[type="search"]').attr('aria-label', 'search');`

resulting in this html and no errors:

`<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="data-table" aria-label="search">`

---

The following will clear that error:

`$('input[type="search"]').attr('aria-label', 'search');`

resulting in this html:

`<label><input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="data-table" aria-label="search" style=""></label>`

The following links helped me:

- [target input by type selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221094/target-input-by-type-and-name-selector)
- [how to add aria-label to nav using jquery](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-add-aria-label-to-nav-using-jquery/217658)